# Is my proof of second fundamental theorem of calculus (without mean value theorem) valid?

Tags: calculus

> ### **Second Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus (The Evaluation Theorem):**
>
> For the function $f$ continuous everywhere in the $[A, B]$, and the
>   function $F$ whose derivative with respect to $x$ equals to $f$:
>
> $$\int_A^B f(x)dx = F(B) - F(A)$$

---

Let $P = \{x_i\}$ to be a regular partition of the closed interval from $A$ to $B$, where $i = 1, 2, 3, ..., n$. Then lets construct the Riemann Series for the function $f$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x$$

By the definition, limit of the series will be equal to the integral of $f$ within the same closed interval:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x = \int_A^B f(x)dx$$

Where

$$\Delta x = \frac{B - A}{n}$$
$$x_i = A + i*\Delta x$$

and so that

$$x_0 = A$$
$$x_n = A + n*\frac{B - A}{n} = A + B - A = B.$$

Since we also know that

$$n \to \infty \Rightarrow \Delta x \to 0 $$ 
$$f(x_i) = F'(x_i)$$
$$f(x_i) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{F(x_i) - F(x_i - \Delta x)}{\Delta x},$$

we can write that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{B - A}{\Delta x}} f(x_i)\Delta x.$$

And following that we can notate the series **without need of a second limit via applying the limit of $\Delta x$ to each element of the sum** (Also look to the clarificiation at the bottom of the question) as

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{B - A}{\Delta x}} \frac{F(x_i) - F(x_i - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}\Delta x = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{B - A}{\Delta x}} F(x_i) - F(x_i - \Delta x),$$

which is that

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{B - A}{\Delta x}} F(x_i) - F(x_i - \Delta x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n F(x_i) - F(x_{i - 1}).$$

And so what we obtain is equivalent with

$$(F_1 - F_0) + (F_2 - F_1) + (F_3 - F_2) + ... + (F_n - F_{n-1})$$

which is nothing but

$$F_n - F_0 = F(x_n) - f(x_0) = F(B) - F(A).$$

Following that:

$$\int_A^B f(x)dx = F(B) - F(A)$$

Q.E.D.

Clarification for the part *"without need of a second limit via applying the limit of $\Delta x$ to each element of sum"*:

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} f(x_i)\Delta x = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (f(x_i)) * \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (\Delta x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (\frac{F(x_i) - F(x_i - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}) * \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (\Delta x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (\frac{F(x_i) - F(x_i - \Delta x)}{\Delta x} * \Delta x). $$

So we can continue with

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{B - A}{\Delta x}} \frac{F(x_i) - F(x_i - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}\Delta x. $$

Comment: In spirit, yes.  To get it airtight, you need to invoke the MVT somewhere.

Comment: I just see one little notation error, in the second to last line, shouldn’t it be $F(x_n)-F(x_0)$ instead?

Comment: $F_n = F(x_n)$ and $F_0 = F(x_0)$. Also $x_n = B$ and $x_0 = A$. So notation error i think?

Comment: Sorry, i mean "So No* notation error i think?"

Comment: I mean technically you need the mean value theorem to be able to say $f(x_i)\Delta x=F(x_i)-F(x_i-\Delta x)$, right?

Comment: If we divide both sides to $\Delta x$ we will obtain the difference quotient. What you have said would be true if $\Delta x$ was a constant, but in contrast we have a limit here saying that $\Delta x \to 0$. Coming from the facts $\Delta x = \frac{B - A}{n}$ and $n \to \infty$

Comment: You are abusing notation which hides an issue. Note that $f(x_i) = F’(x_i) = \lim_{t\to 0}( F(x_i)-F(x_i-t))/t$; so the substitution should *really* be from $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{(b-a)/\Delta x}f(x_i)\Delta x$ to $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{(b-a)/\Delta x}(\lim_{t\to 0}(F(x_i)-F(x_i-t))/t)\Delta x$. You really have a nested limit, that you are conflating into a single limit. You would need to justify that the iterated limit is equal to a single limit, I think...

Comment: Sigma notation is just an abstraction for the sum. In the end, $x_i$ is determined by $A + i*\Delta x$. Just think that we are applying the outside limit separately to each element ($f(x_i)*\Delta x$) of the sum. So we can notate the $f(x_i)$ part of multiplication as the derivative of $F$ at the point $x_i$ (using the $\Delta x$ as our infinitesimal if i don't confuse the terms). Other than this $\Delta x$ only affects the number of summed terms.

Comment: "And following that we can notate the series without need of a second limit via applying the limit of $Δx$
 to each element of sum" Well, $$\lim f(x_i ) \Delta x = \lim f(a + i \Delta x) \Delta x = 0,$$ so what do you mean by this?

Comment: Not that, but this: $$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} f(x_i)\Delta x = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (f(x_i)) * \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (\Delta x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (\frac{F(x_i) - F(x_i - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}) * \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (\Delta x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} (\frac{F(x_i) - F(x_i - \Delta x)}{\Delta x} * \Delta x) $$

Comment: So we can continue with $$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{B - A}{\Delta x}} \frac{F(x_i) - F(x_i - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}\Delta x$$

Comment: @İbrahimİpek: I am well aware that sigma notation represents a sum, thank you. The point I made, though, is that you have a limit (as $\Delta x\to 0$) of a limit (as $t\to 0$), which you are saying can be done as a single limit. I am not saying you cannot, but you have to *justify* it; in general, nested limits are not equivalent to single limits, and hand waving by itself does not justify it.

Comment: Since $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \Delta x = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} f(x_i)\Delta x$, your argument says that I can replace each term in your sum with $\Delta x$.

Comment: Note that your “clarification” just compounds the abuse of notation, because the $\Delta x$ in $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}f(x_i)$ in the second expression is **not** the same $\Delta x$ in $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}(F(x_i)-F(x_i-\Delta x))/\Delta x)$ that appears in the third expression. Your $f(x_i)$ is **independent** of $\Delta x$ in the second expression, but the term in the third expression is *not* independent of $\Delta x$, so they cannot represent the same limit variable. It’s just handwaving to pretend that they are the same.

Comment: Small correction: all your limits should be $\Delta x\to 0^+$.

Comment: The reason you need to be careful about the iterated limit: as $n\to\infty$ and as $\Delta x\to 0^+$, the $x_i$ change; they move (except for $x_0$). So you are not taking a single limit $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0^+}(F(x_i)-F(x_i-\Delta x))/\Delta x$ with $x_i$ fixed (so that you can claim this is equal to $f(x_i)$); the $x_i$ changes, so you are really continuously changing what point you are trying to take the derivative for. That’s why I said you need to be careful about that iterated limit, and why it need not be equal to just the one limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your proof would be correct, if you can first prove something like the following:

> **Theorem?** For any increasing integer sequence $b(n)\to \infty$ and double-index sequence $A(k,n)$ such that [insert nice assumptions here...],
>   $$  \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{b(n)}\frac{A(k,n)}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}  \sum_{k=1}^{b(n)} \frac{\lim_{m\to\infty}A(k,m)}n $$

For you, $A(k,m)$ would be something like $\frac{f(x_k + 1/m) - f(x_k)}{1/m}$.
As an indication that this isn't easy, note that it isn't true without additional assumptions:

$$ \frac12 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k/n}n \overset{???}= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\lim_{m\to\infty} k/m}n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{0}n = 0\dots  $$

Answer (score 3):

I once read a similar approach in one of the textbooks meant for high school students of age 16-17 years. As noted in comments the proof is not really a proof but more of a hand-waving.

Since the function $f$ is continuous it is best to notice that in this case the first and second theorems of calculus are essentially the same. But even then one can't avoid mean value theorem. Here is how you can proceed.

> **First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Continuous Functions**: Let the function $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb{R} $ be continuous on $[a, b] $. Then the function $G:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ defined by $$G(x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$$ is differentiable on $[a, b] $ with $G'(x) =f(x) \, \forall x\in[a, b] $.

Now we prove the second fundamental theorem as mentioned in your question using the first theorem mentioned above. Consider the function $h(x) =F(x) - G(x) $ then $h$ is continuous and differentiable on $[a, b] $ with $h'(x) =f(x)-f(x)=0$. By mean value theorem $h$ is constant on $[a, b] $ and let's say $h(x) =k$ for all all $x\in[a, b] $ so that $F(x) =G(x) +k$ for all $x\in[a, b] $.

By definition of $G$ we have $G(a) =0$ and $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=G(b) =G(b) - G(a) =G(b) +k-(G(a) +k) =F(b) - F(a) $$

It is only when the function $f$ is discontinuous the two fundamental theorems of calculus are different and have independent proofs.